# Package x11 was not found in search path?

Tags: command-line

Can someone help me fix this issue? When I try to use "make" it gives me this error. I have searched online for solutions, but none is helping at all as well.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably haven't installed the X11 libraries:

```
sudo apt-get install libx11-dev
```

Looking at your other error, you should also install [`libpng12-dev`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?searchon=contents&keywords=png.h&mode=exactfilename&suite=trusty&arch=any), which provides `png.h`.

Comment: Oh darn it, I will try this command, but I guess I must have missed it when I installed ubuntu 14 .

Comment: On a side note, is your Ubuntu the latest? If it is, do you happen to know why for some people like me pressing the shutdown button will restart pc instead of shutting down?

Comment: Oh yess, I was just about to aska bout the png thing >.< you are awesome!

Comment: @user3718584 It is, and no, I haven't noticed that. You should ask a new question about that.